# stop infinite loop in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got infinite loop running below code, basically I try to sync props's state with local state

```js
const SomeComponent = ({ ids = [] }) => {
  const selectedIds = useStore(reduxStore);

  const [_, setSelectedIds] = useState(selectedIds);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIds(ids);
  }, [ids]);
};
```

I can't do `if(ids.length) setSelectedIds(ids)` because they will be a case where the setSelectedIds is [], I want to sync it too. But I got infinite loop.

Comment: Maybe you can try setSelectedIds([…id]);

Comment: @parthc why? what's the purpose of that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Basbas then how can I detect props's change for ids? leaving [] means it render once.

Comment: I can only imagine that the `ids` prop value is derived from your redux store and calling `setSelectedIds` changes it, thus re-rendering your component and starting the cycle over. There's not enough information here to provide an answer. Where does `ids` come from?

Comment: Since `ids` is a prop, you don't really need the effect hook. If the prop value changes, your component will re-render anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you set `{ ids = [] }` with `[]` as a default value. If you don't pass `ids` to `SomeComponent`, it will keep initializing `ids` as a new fresh array `[]` that will cause continuous re-renderings

Representing your problem

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React
const SomeComponent = ({ ids = [] }) => {

  const [_, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIds(ids);
  }, [ids]);
  
  console.log('here')
  
  return null
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The possible fix is you should set `{ ids }` instead of being with a default value (if it's empty, leave it as it is)

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React
const SomeComponent = ({ ids }) => {

  const [_, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIds(ids);
  }, [ids]);
  
  console.log('here')
  
  return null
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: is the return null needed in useEffect?

Comment: @JenniferAlexis that `return null` is for rendering your JSX elements (not in `useEffect` as you thought). I put it there because I don't know what you have in JSX

Comment: @JenniferAlexis anything else you have concerned about or something you don't understand? You can reach out to me anytime

Comment: I can't set the default state to [], there's a logic for other feature, so the default state is from redux store.

Comment: You don't need to, you can keep these 2 lines of your code `const selectedIds = useStore(reduxStore); const [_, setSelectedIds] = useState(selectedIds);`. The main problem you addressed in your question is from a default value of `ids` in params, so it basically does not relate to redux store @JenniferAlexis